# Method Not Allowed (POST): /home/

Tags: python, django, forms, view

I have a one page app with a form and a data table. The page load fine, but the problem is the Form is not working when I press the "SUBMIT" Button.

When I press the "SUBMIT" Button it give me this error `Method Not Allowed (POST): /home/`
Thanks you for the help guys!

views.py

```
def _get_form(request, formcls, prefix):
    data = request.POST if prefix in request.POST else None
    return formcls(data, prefix=prefix)


all_items = List.objects.all

class Myview(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'data_list/home.html'
    all_items = List.objects.all

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.render_to_response({'scrape': Scrape(prefix="scrape_pre"), 'all_items': all_items})

    def scrape(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        scrape = _get_form(request, Scrape, 'scrape_pre')
        if request.method == "POST":
            scrape = _get_form(request, Scrape, 'scrape_pre')
            if scrape.is_valid():
                print("Worked")

        return self.render_to_response({'scrape': scrape})


    def home(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        all_items = List.objects.all
        return render(request, "data_list/home.html", {"all_items": all_items})
```

forms.py

```
class Scrape(forms.ModelForm):
    url = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ["item", "site"]
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.add, name="add"),
    path("scrape/", views.scrape, name="scrape"),
    path("home/", views.Myview.as_view(), name="home"),
    path("delete/<list_id>", views.delete, name="delete"),
    path("datacontent/<list_id>", views.datacontent, name="datacontent")
]
```

home.html

```
<div>
    <form action="" method="post" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ scrape|crispy }}
      <pre></pre>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit"  value="Submit">SUBMIT</button>
      <pre></pre><pre></pre><pre></pre><pre></pre>
</form>


</div>

<table class="table">
.....
```

Comment: If you want to make a post call, you should define a `def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`. not a `home(...)`.

Comment: Thank you! it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send a post request (method='post' in the form definition) if your backend doesn't implement the post function, which is responsible for responding the post requests. You should change your 'scrape' function to 'post'.